# Вставить файл в форму

Tags: javascript

У меня есть `blob`, и мне необходимо добавить его к форме чтобы при отправке формы этот файл тоже отправился на сервер.

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Каким образом прикрепить это в `<input type="file">`?

Comment: Я зачем через форму? Так нельзя отправить?

Comment: Там очень большая форма помимо этого, порядка 20 полей, и как-то лень все это отправлять через ajax

Comment: Зачем тогда вставлять, если ест `<in<input type="file">`? А потом на сервере обработать.

Comment: Потому что запись аудио делается из браузера с помощью recorderjs(вроде).

Comment: Вы бы добавили все условия, которые вы прописали в комментариях в сам вопрос.

Comment: Ну и ссылку на сам плагин записи аудио, и кусок HTML, пусть не со всеми 20 полями - тут важно наличие атрибутов `name="..." у этих полей.